# Swift - How to make sure label following slider's thumbnail?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need to develop custom UISlider using swift. The problem is I don't know how to make sure label following slider's thumbnail like following below:

[image]

My code so far

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Slider: UISlider {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.2
        self.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UILabel Over UISlider Thumb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510961/uilabel-over-uislider-thumb)

Comment: You can't use that method if you're using Auto Layout, so that answer doesn't apply to all cases.

Comment: @CihanTek you can not use Auto Layout with UISlider so it apply to all cases.

Comment: Ah, sorry you're right. I've thought of it as a fully custom-made slider that doesn't inherit from UISlider. But you still can't use that method because you can't modify the frames directly while using auto layout.

Comment: I'd like to make clear that if you are using auto layout somewhere you are using it everywhere even if you do not add specific constraints. In this case autoresizing mask will be converted into constraint.

Comment: i'm using autolayout sir.

Comment: @Andrea you are right, but the issue here that you can not connect your constraints to internals of UISlider, only to top view. So all constraints should be based on a rect data provided, but not on internal layout.

Comment: @NikitaLeonov correct!

Answer (score 0):

Probably is worth to take a look at this method, this can't be called directly but you can use it while subclassing

```
func thumbRectForBounds(_ bounds: CGRect,
              trackRect rect: CGRect,
                  value value: Float) -> CGRect
```

More info also on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714405/how-to-get-the-center-of-the-thumb-image-of-uislider) and [here](http://blog.neuwert-media.com/2011/04/customized-uislider-with-visual-value-tracking/)

Comment: i will try it first sir.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact thing for audio files.
The protocol is used to inform the player when user changes the value of the slider.
    func updateSliderPosition(position: Float) 
is called every half second by the player to change position of the slider current value.

```
import UIKit

protocol AudioSliderControlDelegate: class
{
    func audioSliderControlDdiChangeValue(sender: AudioSliderControl, value: Float)
}
class AudioSliderControl: UIControl
{
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentPositionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalDurationLabel: UILabel!

    weak var delegate: AudioSliderControlDelegate?

    private var totalLenght: Double?

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clevooOrange()
        slider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderValueChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        self.addSeperatorToTop()
    }

    //MARK:
    //MARK: - Setup
    func setupForDuration(duration: Double)
    {
        totalLenght = duration
        currentPositionLabel.text = Double(0).formattedDuration()
        totalDurationLabel.text = (duration + 0.5).formattedDuration()
        slider.setValue(0, animated: false)
    }

    func updateSliderPosition(position: Float)
    {
        self.currentPositionLabel.text = (totalLenght! * Double(position)).formattedDuration()
        self.slider.value = position
    }

    //MARK:
    //MARK: - Notification

    func sliderValueChanged(slider: UISlider)
    {
        self.currentPositionLabel.text = (totalLenght! * Double(slider.value)).formattedDuration()
        delegate?.audioSliderControlDdiChangeValue(self, value: slider.value)
    }
}
```