# Size of default thumb image for iOS slider?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uislider

What is the exact size (width, height) of the (default) thumb image for the iOS slider? Is there perhaps some clever way to coax this out of the system (XCode, iOS)?

I tried

```
int thumbWidth = slider.currentThumbImage.size.width;
```

which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714405/how-to-get-the-center-of-the-thumb-image-of-uislider) on this site, but it comes back with 0.

Additional question: The Xcode debugger shows this undocumented variable in the `UISlider`: `CGFloat _hitOffset`. Does anyone by chance know what it is and what it's for?

Comment: working with sizes, you shouldn't use `NSInteger`, better use CGFloat so you can save the exact value!

Answer (score 10):

What about this? Works for me:

```
CGRect trackRect = [self trackRectForBounds:self.bounds];
CGRect thumbRect = [self thumbRectForBounds:self.bounds trackRect:trackRect value:0];
CGSize thumbSize = thumbRect.size;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want change UISlider appearance then use below method

```
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yoursliderimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

as well as below code would change you slider track also

```
UIImage *white = [UIImage imageNamed:@"16x16white.png"];

[movieTimeControl setMinimumTrackImage:[white stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:3.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[movieTimeControl setMaximumTrackImage:[white stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:3.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Aplle HIG document doesn't define any size for UISlider thumb image but it should be under normal image size.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is using a Resizable Image.
But the slider thumb size is 23x23 if you don't want to make the image resizable

Answer (score 0):

There is a session video about UI customization in the WWDC 2012 collection:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=216

You might find your answer here. Its about UISlider customization too

Answer (score 0):

Here is the swift 4 version:

```
yourSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "Knob"), for: .normal)
```