# How to increase uiswitch Thumb size

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to increase thumb size of a `UISwitch` I was trying to increase thumb size by set on the image but the image is not showing.

I try this:

```
uiSwitch.onImage = UIImage(named: "sing")
```

i want switch like this

[here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPF9X.jpg)

Comment: you can not increase the size of UISwitch. For that you need to make your own custom switch or custom library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949300/how-to-resize-a-uiswitch

Comment: i don't want to increase UISwitch. i want to increase thumb size

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369258/size-of-default-thumb-image-for-ios-slider

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPF9X.jpg    it will look like this

Answer (score 3):

```
if let thumbView = try (mySwitch.subviews[0].subviews[3] as? UIImageView) {
       thumbView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:1.5, y: 1.5)
   }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: self explanatory code (thumbView = ...)
I happend to have inspected the internals of UISwitch and found that the 4th subview (index 3) is the thumbView.

Like any another view, you can increase/decrease it size by using the scale transform.

Just incase it wasn't't obvious to some, if apple decides to change the structure of a UISwitch then the code won't work, (but it won't crash either because of the (as?)

Answer (score 2):

Create extension :

```
extension UISwitch {

func increaseThumb(){
    if let thumb = self.subviews[0].subviews[1].subviews[2] as? UIImageView {
        thumb.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX:1.5, y: 1.5)
    }
  }
}
```

Use:

```
 customSwitch.increaseThumb(
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want exactly as image you refered https://github.com/JunichiT/JTMaterialSwitch

If you want to increase the only the thumb size of the UISwitch itself, you can't. You must increase the size of UISwitch.