# Get UISlider thumb rect in vertical position

Tags: ios, uislider, vertical-scrolling

I'm using UISlider in vertical position by transforming.

```
slider.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

But I've to show the tooltip on the left side of slider's thumb. Unless I don't know the rect of the thumb, I cannot show the popover which will look like tooltip view.

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @DianaProdan, no its not possible to do easily. We dropped that idea due to its complexity. Sorry, I couldn't help you.

Comment: This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714405/how-to-get-the-center-of-the-thumb-image-of-uislider